# programming question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody
I understand ROS is an operating system for robots. I have installed it both on a robot and on a linux machine.
I want to write a program that will give me information from the robot's camera(s) and sensors. This program will be a user interface of what the robot sees and senses.
My question might sound very stupid but I have to ask this so I can get it clear in my head: Do I use ROS to write this "user interface program" or do I use a regular programming language like C++ to do this?

Thank you all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47320/programming-question/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the ros wiki to find out more about what ros actually is, in particular [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) page.

ROS is **not** a specific programming language. It is a set of utilities and libraries for implementing all different kinds of functionality on robots. Among other things, it provides many C++ libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1